# How to fail build if test method fails?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

My Reference is this http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms182532.aspx

Using Visual Studio. Lets say there is a Solution `Project.SuperApp` with some projects and one unit test project. If i want to run the tests i first have to build the solution and then run all tests from the Test-Explorer. Even if one test fails the software is already build and ready to deploy. Which seems like an error to me.

With other tools like `Maven` if you want to build/package a software component the tests are executed first. If one test fails the software component is not build/packaged even if it compiles.

How to tell Visual Studio to execute the test cases first and fail the build if one test case fails?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you? You want to run every unit test, regardless of failures. For example, if your 1st 50 tests fail, but you stopped building on failure 1, you will need to build at least 50 times before you get all the failure messages. This will delay your fixes.

Comment: No. The test should not stop on the first failed test. Every test should be executed. But if one test fails there should be no .exe, .dll as output because it obviously has an error.

Comment: I am not sure how Maven works, but I don't see a way to test a library without actually compiling it. You may run some static analysis over your code without building it, but these are not unit tests. And even if you choose to work with say, debug builds for your unit tests, you will usually want to run your tests against the actual, release version at some point (if not unit, then integration tests), because debug versions often have subtle functional differences. And you can easily use a script which will choose whether to copy the output to a "published" folder only if unit tests succeed.

Answer (score 3):

From within TFS (Team Foundation Server, now known as Azure DevOps Server) you can configure it to fail on the tests failing by following these steps:

1. Edit the 'build definition'
2. Select Process
3. Under 2. Basic > Authomated Tests > Select the test assembly and you will see 'Fail Build On Test Failure. Set that to true.

[image]

Comment: What is TFS? Could you please use full words first (followed by an acronym in parentheses) before using acronyms?

Comment: There you go @skittlebiz