# Find out PlatformNotSupportedException during build

Tags: c#, .net-core, cross-platform, code-analysis

I am developing a project for `Windows` using `.NET Core 2.2`. I'm going to build and support it on `Linux` next year. I am looking for a way to flag up an error and break the build if `PlatformNotSupportedException` is used in code.

I've seen the [.NET API analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer) which is still in pre-release phase and not updated since last year.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool or a software library are considered as off-topic, see the [ask] topics.

Comment: Instead of finding such a tool, improve test coverage of your unit/integration test suite, and then you can easily trigger the exceptions by automatic testing.

Comment: @LexLi, good idea with testing. One can test possibility of `PlatformNotSupportedException` in referenced assemblies [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57441394/10958092).

Comment: By the way, @peval27, do you mean exceptions in your code or external dll?

Comment: @Alex I meant exception in the external DLLs

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Mono.Cecil` to check if exception is thrown somewhere in an assembly.

```
public static class ExceptionHelper<TException> where TException : Exception
{
    private static readonly string typeName = typeof(TException).FullName;

    public static void ThrowIfDetected(Assembly assembly)
    {
        var definition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assembly.Location);
        var exceptions = CreateExceptions(definition);
        if (exceptions.Any())
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }

    public static void ThrowIfDetected(params Assembly[] assemblies) =>
        ThrowIfDetected(assemblies as IEnumerable<Assembly>);

    public static void ThrowIfDetected(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
    {
        var exceptions = CreateExceptions(assemblies);
        if (exceptions.Any())
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Exception> CreateExceptions(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies) =>
        assemblies.Select(assembly => AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assembly.Location))
                  .SelectMany(definition => CreateExceptions(definition));

    private static IEnumerable<Exception> CreateExceptions(AssemblyDefinition definition)
    {
        var methods =
                definition.Modules
                          .SelectMany(m => m.GetTypes())
                          .SelectMany(t => t.Methods)
                          .Where(m => m.HasBody);
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            var instructions = method.Body.Instructions
                .Where(i => i.OpCode.Code == Code.Newobj && // new object is created
                            ((MethodReference)i.Operand).DeclaringType.FullName == typeName && // the object is 'TException'
                            i.Next.OpCode.Code == Code.Throw); // and it's immediately thrown
            foreach (var i in instructions)
            {
                var message = $"{definition.FullName} {method.FullName} offset {i.Offset} throws {typeName}";
                yield return new Exception(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get referenced assemblies use such an extension method:

```
public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static Assembly[] ReflectionOnlyLoadReferencedAssemblies(this Assembly assembly) =>
        assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                .Select(a => Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(a.FullName))
                .ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

Create a new console application and add a reference to an assembly with the above code. Try:

```
try
{
    ExceptionHelper<PlatformNotSupportedException>.ThrowIfDetected(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().ReflectionOnlyLoadReferencedAssemblies());
}
catch(AggregateException e)
{
    foreach (var inner in e.InnerExceptions)
        Console.WriteLine($"{inner.Message}\n");
}
```

It gives:

```
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Void System.Environment::SetEnvironmentVariable(System.String,System.String) offset 82 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.String System.Environment::InternalGetFolderPath(System.Environment/SpecialFolder,System.Environment/SpecialFolderOption,System.Boolean) offset 75 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Void System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier::.ctor(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType,System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier) offset 49 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Int32 System.Security.Principal.Win32::CreateWellKnownSid(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType,System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier,System.Byte[]&) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Boolean System.Security.Principal.Win32::IsEqualDomainSid(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier,System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Int32 System.Security.Principal.Win32::GetWindowsAccountDomainSid(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier,System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier&) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Boolean System.Security.Principal.Win32::IsWellKnownSid(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier,System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.IntPtr System.StubHelpers.HStringMarshaler::ConvertToNative(System.String) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.IntPtr System.StubHelpers.HStringMarshaler::ConvertToNativeReference(System.String,System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.HSTRING_HEADER*) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.String System.StubHelpers.HStringMarshaler::ConvertToManaged(System.IntPtr) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Void System.StubHelpers.SystemTypeMarshaler::ConvertToNative(System.Type,System.StubHelpers.TypeNameNative*) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Void System.StubHelpers.SystemTypeMarshaler::ConvertToManaged(System.StubHelpers.TypeNameNative*,System.Type&) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Int32 System.StubHelpers.HResultExceptionMarshaler::ConvertToNative(System.Exception) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Exception System.StubHelpers.HResultExceptionMarshaler::ConvertToManaged(System.Int32) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.IntPtr System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal::StringToHString(System.String) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.String System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal::PtrToStringHString(System.IntPtr) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException

mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Void System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal::FreeHString(System.IntPtr) offset 17 throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException
```

Now you can use it in unit testing (e.g. with `NUnit`) to check automatically if your referenced assemblies can throw `PlatformNotSupportedException`

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void ReferencedAssembliesDoNOtThrowPlatformNotSupportedException()
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => ExceptionHelper<PlatformNotSupportedException>.ThrowIfDetected(yourAssembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadReferencedAssemblies()));
    }
}
```

and break the build if testing fails like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045028/how-to-fail-build-if-test-method-fails).

Comment: but this means that the test will fail even if I am not using that a method that throws PlatformNotSupportedException. I can reference an assemblt that throws PlatformNotSupportedException, I don't want to use that specific method.

Comment: @peval27, you can use a piece of code in `foreach (var method in methods)` to test a single method.

Comment: ok I follow you. It might be a possibility, but then you need to keep note of any new method the code base is using, which seems error prone. thanks anyway

Comment: @peval27, you can find methods in referenced assemblies and then you can find calls to those methods from your assembly programmatically like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433300/list-all-references-calling-a-method-using-mono-cecil/43608685).

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `.NET Compiler Platform SDK` to create your own rules. You can find installation guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).
You can have some troubles with installation. Solution is [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457486/net-compiler-platform-not-working).
When done

- In Visual Studio, choose File > New > Project... Analyzer with code fix (.NET Standard). Name it `PlatformNotSupportedExceptionAnalyzer`.
- In Solution Explorer remove all projects except `PlatformNotSupportedExceptionAnalyzer`.
- From `PlatformNotSupportedExceptionAnalyzer` remove `.cs` and `.resx` files.
- Add new class `Analyzer`.

---

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

// ...

[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class Analyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static readonly string typeName =
        typeof(System.PlatformNotSupportedException).FullName;

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor rule =
        new DiagnosticDescriptor(id: "ThrowsPlatformNotSupportedException",
                                 title: "Throws 'PlatformNotSupportedException'",
                                 messageFormat: "Do not throw 'PlatformNotSupportedException'",
                                 category: "Usage",
                                 defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
                                 isEnabledByDefault: true,
                                 description: "Throws 'PlatformNotSupportedException'");

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics =>
        ImmutableArray.Create(rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context) =>
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.ThrowStatement);

    private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.Node.ChildNodes().SingleOrDefault() is ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax node))
            return;

        var type = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node).Type;
        if ($"{type.ContainingNamespace}.{type.Name}".Equals(typeName))
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(rule, context.Node.GetLocation()));
    }
}
```

---

- Build solution

Test it:

- Create new project.
- Go to Manage NuGet Packages... -> Settings.
- Add new package source.
- Set location to your `PlatformNotSupportedExceptionAnalyzer` `\bin\Debug` folder.
- Name it `AnalyzerSource` and save.
- Set package source to `AnalyzerSource`
- In Browse select `PlatformNotSupportedExceptionAnalyzer` and install it.

Now try:

```
throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
```

ang get error:

> Error ThrowsPlatformNotSupportedException Do not throw 'PlatformNotSupportedException'

[image]

You can control it with `#pragma warning disable` and `#pragma warning restore` like this:

[image]

or with `SuppressMessageAttribute` like this:

[image]

You also can change its severity is Solution Explorer -> Project -> References -> Analyzers -> Your Analyzer

[image]

[image]

Comment: this assumes I am building the source code that throws PlatformNotSupportedException, while I am referencing standard .NET assemblies..

Comment: @peval27, I tried to make that clear. Anyway the solution could be helpful.